# Problems with Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

Im trying to implement **`schema.org`** tags, we have coded a rule that every newly generated article should automatically mark **`author`**, **`date`** etc.

But for some reason it does not fully validate them :

[**Here**](https://www.betxpert.com/artikel/uro-i-vm-truppen-simon-kjaer-og-dbu-i-strid-om-nordicbet-aftale) is an example of a article we have made.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include markup (a minimal example!) that gives the error, and quote the error messages.

Comment: What tool is telling you that it is not fully valid. And what is that tool saying?

Comment: Why do you have a `<font>` tag within a `<font>` tag.  Or more prominently... why do you have a `<font>` tag.  Perhaps the reason your code is not validating is because it is invalid code?  Both `<font>` tags to the same thing as well.

Comment: Not sure if this matters but I would put itemtype before itemprop and itemscope